# Node.js + Socket IO + Apache + PHP remove port from url?

Tags: php, jquery, apache, node.js, socket.io

I have a few questions regarding using socket IO with PHP and such, I am new to nodejs/socket io so I know very little, I have just started using it over the past few days and I'm getting to the point where I will be implementing this onto my website (as of now I have just been building little test examples).

Question: Currently I have to add the port to my localhost in order to view it and have it work, obviously I can't have this when it's a live website, and I also can't do this when I use php pages (just have been doing examples with html) If I'm using port 4000 for my socket io server I have to go to: localhost:4000, however I need to be able to go to: localhost:8888/mysitefolder    (8888 is the port for my MAMP, for php and everything) I have seen in questions where people have solved this but I have been unable to get it to work for my self.

Here is my code:

chat.js

```
 var app = require('express').createServer(), 
      io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(4000);


var users = [];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.emit('connected');

 socket.on('userID', function (userID) {
users.push(userID);
});  


socket.on('message', function (message) {
socket.broadcast.emit('message-response', { data: message});
});

});
```

index.html

```
<title>Testing</title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function mktime(){
  var newDate = new Date;
  return newDate.getTime();
  }

  function appendMessage(data)
   {
  $("body").append(data+"<br />");  
   }

  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
    socket.on('connected', function () {

   //select id from database in real environment
   socket.emit("userID", mktime());

    });



     socket.on('message-response', function (message) {

     appendMessage(message.data);   

});


    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#input').keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode != 13) return;
          var msg = $("#input").val();

             if (msg) {


       socket.emit('message', msg );
       appendMessage(msg);

        $("#input").val('').focus();
      }
    });
    });



    </script>

    <body>
    <input type="text" id="input"><br>
    </body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I need to be able to go to: localhost:8888/mysitefolder'? All that you need to do is to reference the js file correctly like: "localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js" and that's it. You don't even need an Express server, you can serve the index file with the JS code.

Comment: Well localhost:8888 is where MAMP runs on, for php and everything, mysitefolder is just the folder inside there for php files to work.

also, what do I change in my two files? I just quickly tried and there's an error. (Like i said, im new with this, so im not sure how everything works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean that you do not want to hard code a port or url in the client? Is that right?

In socket.io 0.8.7, you don't need to provide it. You can just use the following and it will be autodetected

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, did I get your request right then? I have a working socket.io using emit where I do not provide the URL and port. I only provide port on server side not client - <https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo/tree/socket_emit>

Comment: That wasn't my initial issue, my initial issue was that I thought you had to have the port in the URL itself, in the bar. I did not know the only reason that it didnt work without it was because it referenced the socket.io script. The solution was changing:

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
to:
<script src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: I had wondered why there was no other directory specific in that, everything I had read about it made it sound like socket.io just found it magically, haha. However, anyways. With what you are doing is not working for me either, I have to have this:
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost", {port: 4000});

without anything specified like you have done just doesn't work.